# Application Load balancer DNS is working but CloudFront failed to connect Application Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer

My app structure is like the default traffic goes to S3 and traffic to `/api` will go to the application load balancer for my Node.js app API backend. My application has been set up and it's working when I test it like: `myapplicationloadbalancerDNS:5000`.

I have created a CloudFront with Alternate domain names with my domain name and add one origin - S3, and create a Default(*) to this S3 origin. It's working when I test with my domain `mydomainname.com`

I'm trying to create another distruibution to `/api` pointing to my ALB. On this setting, my origin domain is the ALB and protocal is `HTTPS only`. On its Behaviors setting, I created Path pattern: `/api`, origin and origin groups is the ALB, viewer is `Redirect HTTP to HTTPS`, Cache key and origin requests is `Legacy cache settings` with `Include the following headers` and `Host` on `Add Header`.

Then, when I test my domain on api link, `mydomainname.com/api`, I got 503 error. Even the link, `mydomainname.com/api:5000`, I got AccessDenied error.

Answer (score 0):

> On this setting, my origin domain is the ALB and protocal is HTTPS only

You have to **properly setup https on the ALB**. First, HTTPS works on port 443, not 5000. Then you also need a valid public SSL certificate and your own domain that you associate with the ALB.